# Hyperlink and numbered drop down list in excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

First of all, sorry about my english :)

in Excel (2010) I have a sheet1. There I have 30 test variants (options). Over all options I need to do the drop down list, which contains numbers 1-30 (because I have 30 optionts of test) and need to write code to hyperlink, which sends me to test, which I chose in drop down list.

**How it looks:**

**My test:** (just text)  (**drop down list**)-there I should choose one test option (1-30) (**hyperlink** named "Go")

Then goes 30 test options.

- Test variant  **1**

Task 1

*jjjfjfjfjf*

Task 2

*jdddh*

- Test variant **2**

Task 1

*jjjfjfjfj*

Task 2

*jdddh*

and till...

- Test variant **30**

How I insert drop down list:(data-data validation-choose list-and select data(numbers from 1-30))

I stuggle with hyperlink, because all tutorial shows, how to write hyperlink code if all my tests options would be in apart sheets, but I have all test options in one sheet. 
To hyperlink I used code:  **=HYPERLINK("[DATI_8.xlsx]list!"&B3;"Go")**, where **DATI_8.xlsx** is location, **list!** sheet name where are drop down list, **&B3** drop down adress, **"Go"** just name of hyperlink, but it is not working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something like this (below)

Drop-down is in A1, and cells to jump to are below (but could as well be on a different sheet)

HYPERLINK formula in C1 is as shown.

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!A" & MATCH("Option " & A1,A:A,0),"Go")
```

Uses MATCH() to locate the correct row to jump to.

[image]

Credit to: http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-18-dynamic-hyperlinks-and-the-magic

**EDIT**: this should work for matching on two columns.
Note you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the formula, since it needs to be entered as an array formula.

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!A" &MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A="Var Nr.")*(D:D=A1),0),"Go")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to write the same code, but it showed me an error, I even wrote all the same as you, but still I seen only error (#N/A). Exel says that it do not like ("Option"&A1) part. Maybe you can see where I have mistake : https://fv16.failiem.lv/thumb_show.php?i=wu5hqjyw&view  Thanks!

Comment: You do not have a space after "Option" - it needs to match exactly what is below

Comment: Thanks, I see, however I still have an error in my task. I struggle, because "Option" is in one sheet, but option's number in other. I tried to use IF, wanted to say If found "option" (in photo it will be "Var Nr." , then look in row number (because in collumn I have also numbers) , but excel said that it is too much formulas, then I used INDEX and MATCH, tried to do exaclly as your description says (myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-index-and-match-functions) , but still it is not correct. Sorry, that I am asking so much. https://fv11.failiem.lv/thumb_show.php?i=342qtqdt&view